# First authentication

Tags: apache-marmotta

I have installed (standalone) and correctly started Apache Marmotta 3.3.0 on an Ubuntu server. But I can't log in with the default admin password (`admin`/`pass123`). Navigating to my host:8080, I get to access to the configuration interface. But I can't change anything.

I both tried using Chrome and Safari. By clicking on the login button (top/right) I don't get to log in. If I try to change something through the configuration interface, I'm prompted by the browser with an "authentication required" form. Still the `admin`/`pass123` combination doenn't work.